# What is the difference between these two syntaxes? Are they both closures?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have seen both of these syntaxes (the second one a lot more though)

Is there a difference? Are they both behaving the same way?

```js
(function() {
  // code
}())
```

```js
(function() {
  // code
})()
```

Comment: They're the same. I know this question is a duplicate

Comment: Neither are closures if there are no variables in the outer scope. Both are closures if there are.

Comment: No closure unless they export a function. What you showed us is just an [IEFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Comment: I did the following in the chrome console `var g = (function() {
  alert(1)
}());` and `var h = (function() {
  alert(2)
})();` and finally `h===g;` it returns true. I know it does not help but i found it courious

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree Look at what `g` and `h` actually contain. They are `undefined`, so of course they are `===`. The inner functions don't return anything (they just `alert`)